# Parsing large log files in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Suppose I have several 200mb+ files that I want to grep through. How would I do this in Haskell?

Here's my initial program:

```
import Data.List
import Control.Monad
import System.IO
import System.Environment

main = do
  filename <- liftM head getArgs
  contents <- liftM lines $ readFile filename
  putStrLn . unlines . filter (isPrefixOf "import") $ contents
```

This reads the whole file into memory before parsing through it.
Then I went with this:

```
import Data.List
import Control.Monad
import System.IO
import System.Environment

main = do
  filename <- liftM head getArgs
  file <- (openFile filename ReadMode)
  contents <- liftM lines $ hGetContents file
  putStrLn . unlines . filter (isPrefixOf "import") $ contents
```

I thought since `hGetContents` is lazy, [it will avoid reading the whole file into memory](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/io.html#io.lazy). But running both scripts under `valgrind` showed similar memory usage for both. So either my script is wrong, or `valgrind` is wrong. I compile the scripts using

```
ghc --make test.hs -prof
```

What am I missing? Bonus question: I see a lot of mentions on SO of how Lazy IO in Haskell is actually a bad thing. How / why would I use strict IO?

**Update:**

So it looks like I was wrong in my reading of valgrind. Using `+RTS -s`, here's what I get:

```
 7,807,461,968 bytes allocated in the heap
 1,563,351,416 bytes copied during GC
       101,888 bytes maximum residency (1150 sample(s))
        45,576 bytes maximum slop
             2 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

Generation 0: 13739 collections,     0 parallel,  2.91s,  2.95s elapsed
Generation 1:  1150 collections,     0 parallel,  0.18s,  0.18s elapsed

INIT  time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
MUT   time    2.07s  (  2.28s elapsed)
GC    time    3.09s  (  3.13s elapsed)
EXIT  time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
Total time    5.16s  (  5.41s elapsed)
```

The important line is `101,888 bytes maximum residency`, which says that at any given point my script was using 101 kb of memory at most. The file I was grepping through was 44 mb. So I think the verdict is: `readFile` and `hGetContents` are both lazy.

**Follow-up question:**

Why do I see 7gb of memory allocated on the heap? That seems really high for a script that's reading in a 44 mb file.

**Update to follow-up question**

Looks like a few gb of memory allocated on the heap is not atypical for Haskell, so no cause for concern. Using `ByteString`s instead of `String`s takes the memory usage down a lot:

```
  81,617,024 bytes allocated in the heap
      35,072 bytes copied during GC
      78,832 bytes maximum residency (1 sample(s))
      26,960 bytes maximum slop
           2 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)
```

Comment: Hum, are you sure you don't need to build the whole `unlines` string before actually writing it with `putStrLn`? I would give a try to something like `Control.Monad.forM_ (filter (isPrefixOf "import") contents) $ putStrLn`. It's just a guess however.

Comment: @Riccardo: No, `unlines` can be evaluated lazily.  Try `putStr $ unlines $ map show [1..]` in `ghci`.

Comment: Does -O2 magically solve the problem?

Comment: @gspr: nope. Same thing: `7,807,461,320 bytes allocated in the heap`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both `readFile` and `hGetContents` should be lazy.  Try running your program with `+RTS -s` and see how much memory is actually used.  What makes you think the entire file is read into memory?

As for the second part of your question, lazy IO is sometimes at the root of unexpected [space leaks](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Performance/Space) or [resource leaks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/498309).  Not really the fault of lazy IO in and of itself, but determining whether its leaky requires analyzing how it's used.

Comment: @VladtheImpala: Don't worry about the total allocation figure; it's the *total* amount of memory allocated over the lifetime of the program. It never decreases, even when memory is freed by garbage collection, as happens frequently in Haskell; figures of multiple gigabytes per second aren't uncommon.

Comment: @ehird ah okay, thank you. I just wasn't sure if that was typical or not.

Answer (score 8):

Please, don't use `String`s (especially when processing >100 Mb files).
Just replace them with `ByteString`s (or `Data.Text`):

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Control.Monad
import System.Environment
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as B

main = do
  filename <- liftM getArgs
  contents <- liftM B.lines $ B.readFile filename
  B.putStrLn . B.unlines . filter (B.isPrefixOf "import") $ contents
```

And I bet, this will be several times faster.

**UPD:** regarding your follow-up question.
Amount of allocated memory is strongly connected to the magic speedup when switching to bytestrings.
As `String` is just a generic list, it requires extra memory for each `Char`: pointer to next element, object header, etc. All this memory needs to be allocated and then collected back. This requires a lot of computational power.
On the other side, `ByteString` is a list of *chunks*, i.e. continuous blocks of memory (I think, not less than 64 bytes each). This greatly reduces number of allocations and collections, and improves cache locality also.

Comment: Absolutely agreed on using ByteStrings...I didn't want to complicate things further by adding that to my example. But yes, they are a *huge* savings in terms of both time and memory: `81,617,024 bytes allocated in the heap` with `78,832 bytes maximum residency` and `MUT   time    0.08s  (  0.22s elapsed)` time.